Django docker error with Postgres django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured
Estoy teniendo un problema comunicando mi api de Django que esta corriendo localmente, con mi DB Postgres que esta corriendo en Docker
La DB funciona perfectamente con Adminer.
Pero cuando lo intento con Django (exactamente las mismas credenciales que utilizo en el adminer)...
Boom!
    ...env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 29, in <module>
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module")
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module


    SETTINGS
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': os.getenv("DB_ENGINE"),
            'NAME': os.getenv("DB_NAME"),
            'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
            'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
            'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
            'PORT': os.getenv("DB_PORT")
        },
        'kettle': {
     

       'ENGINE': os.getenv("DB_ENGINE"),
        'NAME': os.getenv("DB_NAME_KETTLE"),
        'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
        'PORT': os.getenv("DB_PORT")
    }
}


ENV
DB_ENGINE='django.db.backends.postgresql'
DB_NAME='database'
DB_USER='postgres'
DB_PASSWORD='1234'
DB_HOST='db'
DB_PORT='5432'

DB_NAME_KETTLE='kettle'
ADMINER_PORT=8080

VIRTUAL ENV
asgiref==3.8.1
certifi==2024.6.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==42.0.8
Django==4.2.3
django-cors-headers==4.2.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
idna==3.7
psycopg==3.1.19
psycopg2==2.9.6
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
pycparser==2.22
PyJWT==2.3.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2024.1
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.5.0
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1

And in my Docker, postgres is in the port 5432:5432.
Mi postgres/docker esta corriendo en el 5432:5432

Al fin lo logre! El problema fue bastante simple. Tenia otro postgres corriendo en mi maquina local. Lo unico que falta ahora es... Postgres... REPARA ESTO!! ESTUVE 2 DIAS PELEANDO CON ESTO Y POSTGRES NO AYUDO EN LO MAS MINIMO... NINGUN ERROR... NADA

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
